# why git push origin master fails?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I want to push my local project on my bitbucket's repository. But it fails. See:

[image]

Does anybody what's wrong?

Comment: Did you try *reading the message*, which tells you both what the problem is and what to do about it?

Comment: Please so not post screenshots.

Comment: Also, there is no evidence you read the error message.

Comment: hint: look at the hint

Comment: @coredump there is 5 hints, which one do you mean exactly ?

Comment: all of them, you can't push because there is a conflict, pull and merge locally

Comment: @jonrsharpe the erroe says "fetch first" ..! But I don't want that. I want to push my new edition on the repository as a new commit .. that's it.

Comment: You can't push if the local history is different to the remote one.

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite what's already there? How have you ended up in this situation?

Comment: @choroba Oh .. good point, because recently I've changed my windows OS and I don't have any local history. What should I do now?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Because I've changed lots of my codes ..!

Comment: @stack: Do you mean `git log` returns nothing?!

Comment: @choroba [`git log`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex1UG.png)

Comment: But the remote being different suggests *someone else has done that too*. So either you have managed to break it yourself somehow (how?) or you can't push without overwriting somebody else's work. I'd recommend running through an introduction to the tool you're using before continuing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Look, I don't care about my old codes. just I want to push my new version. this current version is the one I want to protect it on bitbucket.

Comment: Then you can force push. But please gain some idea of what you're doing before continuing to do it; if you're the only one using this repo, you've really got no excuse to be in this state.

Comment: @jonrsharpe as git said, I executed `git fetch`, and then `git merge`, now it says: `fatal: No remote for the current branch`. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: I can only repeat my previous advice; all of this is covered in existing docs, tutorials and other questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In git when ever you try to `push` code to the remote server git using a command names [`merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to find out what is the last commit which was "downloaded" from the server.

[image]

Once the commit is found git "ask" the server to retrieve the changes and merge them locally to your local branch.

In your case the server found out that since the last time you have pulled from the server that are more changes which you dont have locally so you have to `pull` your changes into your local branch.

#### `git pull`

`git pull` is an alias for 2 commands, `git fetch && git merge`. `git fetch` downalod all your changes to your local git repository and `git merge` will add them to your local working directory.

In your case its one of the most simple thing to do in git, you simply have to pull the changes from the server into your local branch.

Git inform you about it and you simply have to pull the changes.

[image]
[image]